# Need help to convert the following semantic tableau to Fitch style proof

Tags: symbolic-logic

[image]

**Derive ~M**

1.~R & ~W.

2.[(R=W)v(Mv G)]=>(W=M).

As you see, the tableaux is valid.So l want to translate it
an SL derivation(Fitch style)

**Here is my understanding**

1 ~R.     1 => E

2 ~W.     1 => E

3|-[(R=W)v(MVG)]. 2=>E

4 |--(R=W).        3.Assume

5 | R.           Assume

6.| W.           4-6 =E

7 W.            4-7 V I

8.|—-(MVG).     Assume
?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From not-R and not-W derive R=W and use or-intro to derive the antecedent of 2nd premise, from which derive W=M. With not-W, derive not-M.

Comment: Thanks l did it in my notes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a homework forum

Comment: It is not a home work problem! @SwamiVishwananda. I am 58 and graduated Concordia U in 1993

Comment: Who downvoted me -1 ? Please upvote me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first five lines say: Assume `M` under the premises, and there derive `~R` and `~W` (we do this by *conjunction elimination*).  Well, in fitch you put the premise first, then  raise the assumption.

Now the left branch of line 6 says `(R = W) v (M v G)` must be derivable (under the assumptions) since assuming it to be false leads to contradictions on all paths.  So we shall derive it.

Since we do not have a way to derive M or G, we look to deriving R = W by *biconditional introduction*, then using *disjunction introduction* and finally *condition elimination*

This brings us to the right branch of your line 6, which says a contradiction can be derived from here, and indeed having derived `M = W`, `M`, and `~W` we can do so (hint: *biconditional elimination*).  And having derived a contradiction under the assumption of `M`, we use *negation introduction* to discharge the assumption and so deduce its negation: `~M`

```
  |  ~R & ~W
  |_ [(R = W) v (M v G)] > (W = M)
  |  |_ M
  |  |  ~R
  |  |  ~W
  |  |  :
  |  |  :
  |  |  :
  |  |  :
  |  |  :
  |  |  :
  |  |  R = W
  |  |  (R = W) v (M v G)
  |  |  W = M
  |  |  :
  |  |  :
  |  |  #
  |  ~M
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer

Comment: Why did l get downvoted